# Serial fields at 1 after logical replication

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm migrating my database from one server to another.

So far I've done `pg_dump -s` and I was able to successfully transfer the schema to my new server. As for the data I went with logical replication, all of the tuples are where they should be, but trying to insert another row leads to an error saying `Key (id) = (1)` already exists. Is replication the wrong tool for the job, or is there a way to get the tables up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by dumping just the sequences with `pg_dump -t '*_id_seq' dbname > sequences.sql`